# angular material string-array to pre-multi-selected mat-select to display data in more user-friendly format

Tags: arrays, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, mat-table

Want to display a string-array in a mat-select. That mat-select should show the data as pre-selected (multiple) format. By clicking on it, the options should be showed, but no changes should be possible. The mat-select is part of a mat-table entry and should be only a view-cell defined in html-template-code (should not change the data of the table-data-source).

Took example of angular-material-select-documentation, but even cannot get it to show the data, without to select it manually.

```js
<ng-container matColumnDef="letters">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Letters</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data; let i = index;">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label></mat-label>
      <mat-select multiple [ngModel]="data.letters">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let letter of data.letters" checked disabled>
          {{letter}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "check" options in a multi-select control by adding their `value` to the select's model:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="letters">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Letters</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data; let i = index;">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label></mat-label>
      <mat-select multiple [ngModel]="data.letters">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let letter of data.letters" [value]="letter" disabled>
          {{letter}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Your solution has fixed my problem. Thank you. :)